# How to make click toggle event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make click toggle event with this code

**HTML**

```
 <a class="load" data-gallery="123456" style="cursor: pointer;"><h2><p>example</p></h2></a>
 <div id="123456">

 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('.link').toggle(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('gallery');
    var postData = {
        "c": id
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: postData,
        url: 'images.php',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#" + id).html("Loading...");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#" + id).html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
 }, function () {
    var id = $(this).data('gallery');
    $("#" + id).html("");
 });
```

but with this code, the .load() is not clickable

Thanks

Comment: [toggle-function-function-removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) in jQuery 1.9

Comment: What element has class="link"? (`$('.link').toggle....`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[toggle event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been removed from `jQuery 1.9+`, you could use instead `click` event using following logic:

```
$('.link').click(function () {
    $(this).data('toggle', !$(this).data('toggle'));
    if ($(this).data('toggle')) {
        var id = $(this).data('gallery');
        var postData = {
            "c": id
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: postData,
            url: 'images.php',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#" + id).html("Loading...");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#" + id).html(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var id = $(this).data('gallery');
        $("#" + id).html("");
    }
});
```